# ListIndex of current value of combobox without selection

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

In VBA, the ListIndex property of a Combobox shows the index (starting at 0) of the item selected in the overall list (array) of values in the Combobox.  It shows -1 if there is no selection made.

When I bring up a sheet in Excel with a Combobox and the last value in it, it comes up with a ListIndex of -1, instead of the actual ListIndex of the item.

What is the trick in VBA to quickly getting the ListIndex of the current non-selected value?

I know I could manually check the array myself (the .List property), but I'm hoping that VBA has some quicker way to do this.

Comment: Do you fill the `ComboBox` through the `Add` Method on `Workbook_Open`, seting `ListFillRange` or another Method?

Answer (score 2):

From VBA Help on the **ListIndex** Property:

> The ListIndex property contains an index of the selected row in a
>   list. Values of ListIndex range from –1 to one less than the total
>   number of rows in a list (that is, ListCount – 1). When no rows are
>   selected, ListIndex returns –1. When the user selects a row in a
>   ListBox or ComboBox, the system sets the ListIndex value.

So I assume you aren't selecting anything, but trying to read the selected value. That might explain why ListIndex returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to retrieve the index of the displayed item in the combo.

```
        Dim dst As Worksheet: Set dst = Worksheets("MyData")
        MsgBox (dst.OLEObjects("combobox1").Object.ListIndex)
```